# During Torah reading service, is a Cohen allowed to forgo a Levi Aliyah?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, torah-reading

[Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayyim 135:8](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayyim.135.8?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) says that during Torah reading, if there is a Cohen present but no Levi, the Cohen gets the first two *aliyot*.

Let's say that on a Monday or Thursday, when there are only 3 aliyot, two *Yisra'elim* **need** to be honored - e.g. a Bar Mitzvah boy and an aufruf. (See explanation, below.) Can the Cohen forgo receiving the Levi aliyah and can that be given to a *Yisra'el*?

(I have not used *chatan* or *sandak* since there is an opinion mentioned in OC stating that for these two people, you may be able to add a 4th aliyah even on a weekday.)

**Explanation:**

In my shul, congregants get easily offended if you don't give them an aliyah on a special occasion. In this scenario, there is a Bar Mitzvah and aufruf on a Monday. The Cohen is the Bar Mitzvah boy's grandpa. If we don't give aliyot to each of the other two, they would be so offended, that we could lose these regular "minyanaires". It is difficult to get subs. Thus, they **need** to get these aliyot.

Comment: *Need* to be honored?

Comment: Have the kohen leave

Comment: @DoubleAA - See the explanation, above. The Cohen is one of the honorees who must also get an aliyah.

Comment: Ah. Honestly, it sounds more like your congregants **need** to get over themselves.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Perhaps, you've never dealt with elderly rich Conservative-shul congregants. The key word, here, is "rich". I.e. - they support the shul w/o appearing most of the time. So, for the few times that they do appear, it "pays" to humor them. In short, the shul *needs* them more than they need the shul ;-)

Comment: If you can get enough people together for the event, make two Torah readings.

Comment: @Yishai - That doesn't answer my question, but +1 for the innovative and simple idea, if it could work. Keep in mind that I mentioned that this was a weekday situation. Creating another Torah minyan, if we could do it, would possibly be *tircha d'tzibbur*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[הלכה - דיני קריאת התורה by Rabbi Naftali Hoffner](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43399&st=&pgnum=77) says that after a Kohain gets an Aliya, if there is no Levi, the same Kohain must get the next Aliya. He bases this on [Mishna Berura 135:28](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=33).

What is done in my Shul when 2 people who are both Yisraelim need an Aliya is that one receives Hagba instead. The Rabbi himself took Hagba in such a situation and thus no one is insulted if that is what they receive.